# C# Pattern Match for Downloaded Movies

Tags: c#, regex

Hi I am after a pattern match that will allow me to get a match collection out of a file name after a film has downloaded. Example of files are

```
The.Voices.2014.720p.BDRip.x264.AC3-WiNTeaM.avi
13.Sins.2014.1080p.BluRay.DTS.x264-HDS.mkv
A.Million.Ways.to.Die.in.the.West.2014.1080p.WEB-DL.x264.AC3-EVO.mkv
Ant-Man.2015.1080p.BluRay.x264-SPARKS.mkv
```

I wanted to be able to extract the name of the movie without periods, the year and the quality.

I don't think it's a guarantee that these come in this order so ideally the pattern need to be flexible.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: For movies after 2000 the match is `.20`, but you have to include also `.19` to cover all years.

Comment: I'm looking for a complete regular expression I can use against the Regex.Matches method for returning these groups

Comment: *"I don't think it's a guarantee that these come in this order so ideally the pattern need to be flexible"* - this requirement suddenly make it impossible (shall I say *much harder*?). If you have a list of what can be included into file name (e.g. list of all codecs in all variations of spelling: `AC3`, `x264`, then all releasers names lol), then you can remove those one by one until there is only movie name left.

Comment: You're going to need more than a simple `Regex.Match` for this.  I would recommend writing a function that takes the filename as an arg and iterates through each section (after going through a `string.Split('.')`) to look for known common value types and put them into an array or dictionary.  It sounds complicated, but it will help minimize misreads.  xxxp or xxxxp is the resolution, 19xx or 20xx is the year, xyyy (and a slew of others) is the video codec, AC3, Dolby, etc is the audio codec, the final .xxx or .xxxx is the file format.

Comment: The *guarantee* statement is nebulous. Either we are parsing structured data or not. Non structured data, well all bets are off. Also you need to provide to us all different permutations of *valid* data. See my *1941* movie added  for a title with a year (will kill other regexs presented, try it) and it has a date different from the 2000's examples you only provided..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> extract the name of the movie without periods, the year and the quality.

Use of a forward negative look ahead ensures that the year will be an anchor for the regex parsing and not necessarily part of the movie title.

*I added the movie with John Belushi entitled 1941 as a test item.*

```
string data =
@"1941.1981.1080p.WEB-DL.x264.AC3-EVO.mkv
The.Voices.2014.720p.BDRip.x264.AC3-WiNTeaM.avi
13.Sins.2014.1080p.BluRay.DTS.x264-HDS.mkv
A.Million.Ways.to.Die.in.the.West.2014.1080p.WEB-DL.x264.AC3-EVO.mkv
Ant-Man.2015.1080p.BluRay.x264-SPARKS.mkv";

string pattern = @"

^(?<Name>.+?)                  # Movie Name up to year and resolution
(?!\.[12]\d\d\d\.\d{,3}[ip]\.) # Year and resolution foward negative look ahead as an a pattern anchor
\.                             # Non captured due to only explicitly capturing.
(?<Year>\d\d\d\d)              # Capture Year, etc...
\.
(?<Resolution>[^.]+)
\.
(?<Format>[^.]+) 

";


Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture          // Only what we ask for (?<> ), ignore non captures
                           | RegexOptions.Multiline                // ^ makes each line a separate one.
                           | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace) // Allows us to comment pattern only.
     .OfType<Match>(
     .Select (mt => new
                    {
                        Movie      = Regex.Replace(mt.Groups["Name"].Value, @"\.", " "),
                        Year       = mt.Groups["Year"].Value,
                        Resolution = mt.Groups["Resolution"].Value,
                        Format     = mt.Groups["Format"].Value,
                    });
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: He wanted film name without periods.

Comment: @jdweng I added the regex replace on the final output to handle that. OP didn't say it had to be in one regex. :-)

Comment: Why use regex replace when string replace is more efficient.

Comment: @jdweng Good point...I tend to think in Regex before string functions; vs everyone else who thinks of string functions first.

Comment: This seems closest to what I want, was 2/3rds of the way through writing this myself and pretty similar to what I had. Thanks I'll mark this as answer as it's close enough

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex with rightoleft option

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] inputs = {
                "The.Voices.2014.720p.BDRip.x264.AC3-WiNTeaM.avi",
                "13.Sins.2014.1080p.BluRay.DTS.x264.HDS.mkv",
                "A.Million.Ways.to.Die.in.the.West.2014.1080p.WEB-DL.x264.AC3-EVO.mkv",
                "Ant-Man.2015.1080p.BluRay.x264.SPARKS.mkv"
            };

            string pattern = @"(?'title'.*)\.(?'year'[^\.]+)\.(?'pixelsize'[^\.]+)\.(?'format'[^\.]+)\.(?'formatsize'[^\.]+)\.(?'filename'[^\.]+)\.(?'extension'[^\.]+)";
            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
                string extension = match.Groups["extension"].Value;
                string fileName = match.Groups["filename"].Value;
                string formatSize = match.Groups["formatsize"].Value;
                string format = match.Groups["format"].Value;
                string pixelSize = match.Groups["pixelsize"].Value;
                string year = match.Groups["year"].Value;
                string title = match.Groups["title"].Value;
                title = title.Replace(".", " ");

                Console.WriteLine("title = {0}, year = {1}, pixel size = {2}, Format = {3}, format size = {4}, filename = {5}.{6}",
                    title, year, pixelSize, format, formatSize,fileName, extension);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: I am not seeing the value of having the regex use right to left; specially since you are using named captures which defeats the purpose of returning the match captures in reverse order. Also why are you showing 'Main' and includes...why waste time with the test program; just divine the answer into its smallest form. Too much too read. IMHO

Comment: There are multiple periods in the film name.   So I have .* for film name which gets the entire filename no matter the number of periods.  For this to work you need right to left option.

Comment: As a thought, would `.+?` work instead of `.*`. There will be at least one letter at least, not zero as in `*`. The `*` just gives the parser more backtracking situations when there will never be one.

Comment: When I have more time I am going to investigate your usage of the right ot left. Plus one from me.

Comment: If I put the dollar sign at the end of the pattern then the right to left wouldn't be needed.  Regex will start from the left.  There will be no difference between .+ and .* when they is at least one match.